# How to use RxJava in Android?

Tags: android

I studied many posts about RxJava. But not know its usage still.
Such as I have a OnSearchListener in My MainListAdapter,
My MainActivity implements it, how do I can use RxJava simply 
the program?

Comment: If my description have any problem, tell me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make `subject` at your `MainActity` for publishing data like this.

```
BehaviorSubject<T> dataPublisher = BehaviorSubject.create();
```

this is the way to publish data.

```
List<T> dataList = getDatas(...);
dataPublisher.onNext(dataList);
```

Add `subscription` at your `adapter` like this.

```
public class MyAdatper<T> extends BaseAdapter {

    Subscription dataSubscription;

    public MyAdapter(BehaviorSubject<T> publisher) {
        this.dataSubscription = publisher
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Observer<T>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {}

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {}

                @Override
                public void onNext(T data) {
                    // your implementation
                }
            });
    }

    // your implementation
}
```

`T` means generic as you know, replace it to your data class.
Don't forget `unsubscribe` at `onDestroy`

I hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, have many people think the problem description not clear, only you figure out it  :)